# Drop down End time change based on Start time using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select drop down for Start time and End Time. My start time starts from 07:00 and end time ends until 07:00 the next day. I want my end time to change such that when user select 19:00 for start time, the end time drop down should automatically list down from 20:00 until 07:00. How can i achieve this using JS? Thank you

```html
        Start Time:
        <select name='start' id='start'>
            <option value='07:00'>07:00</option>
            <option value='07:00'>08:00</option>
            <option value='07:00'>09:00</option>
            .......
            <option value='23:00'>23:00</option>
            <option value='00:00'>00:00</option>
            .......
            <option value='05:00'>05:00</option>
            <option value='06:00'>06:00</option>
            <option value='07:00'>07:00</option>
        </select>
        End Time:
        <select name='end' id='end'>
            <option value='07:00'>07:00</option>
            <option value='07:00'>08:00</option>
            <option value='07:00'>09:00</option>
            ........
            <option value='23:00'>23:00</option>
            <option value='00:00'>00:00</option>
            .......
            <option value='05:00'>05:00</option>
            <option value='06:00'>06:00</option>
            <option value='07:00'>07:00</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Start Time:
        <select name='start' id='start' onchange="$('#end').find('option').each(function( key, value ) { if(parseInt($(value).val())<parseInt($('#start').val())) {$(value).hide();} else {$(value).show();}   });">
            <option value='7'>07:00</option>
            <option value='8'>08:00</option>
            <option value='9'>09:00</option>
            .......
            <option value='23'>23:00</option>
            <option value='0'>00:00</option>
            .......
            <option value='5'>05:00</option>
            <option value='6'>06:00</option>
            <option value='7'>07:00</option>
        </select>
        End Time:
        <select name='end' id='end'>
            <option value='7'>07:00</option>
            <option value='8'>08:00</option>
            <option value='9'>09:00</option>
            ........
            <option value='23'>23:00</option>
            <option value='0'>00:00</option>
            .......
            <option value='5'>05:00</option>
            <option value='6'>06:00</option>
            <option value='7'>07:00</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).